# Finding value from another one in an array of arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I got the follwing array and I would like to retrieve the name by the id:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => john
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => mark
        )
etc...
```

It is doable with double foreach loop and a conditional test, but is there a more elegant way?

Comment: A `foreach` is probably the quickest way of doing this as most other ways involve at least 1 pass of the entire array to convert it to a id => name array (unless you can generate this in the first place).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array_column to map ids to names:

```
<?php

$arr = [
    ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'Rolf'],
    ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Gary'],
    ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'Jimmy'],
];


$id_names = array_column($arr, 'name', 'id');

var_export($id_names);

print $id_names[3];
```

Output:

```
array (
  1 => 'Rolf',
  3 => 'Gary',
  2 => 'Jimmy',
)Gary
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `id` is unique...

#### Long Version

```
$arr = [
    ['id'=1, 'name'='john'],
    ['id'=2, 'name'='mark'],
];

$lookup = [];
foreach($arr as $row) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    $lookup[$id] = $name;
}

// find name for id, 2
echo $lookup[2];

// ==> mark
```

#### Short Version

...see Progrock’s solution!